# Where Does the ECUAbstractionSoftwareComponent Reside in AUTOSAR ? ASW or BSW Layer?

Tags: autosar

I have studied about `SoftwareComponentType` from the AUTOSAR `SoftwareComponentTemplate` specification document and came to the `ECUAbstractionSoftwareComponent`, since this type is one of the `AtomicSoftwareComponent` I want to know where does this special type of software component placed. it will be designed and configured as an ASW software component or it will be placed inside the ECU abstraction layer from the BSW layers ??!.

Also, please give me a reference to a case study in which the use of `ECUAbstractionSoftwareComponent` with `Sensor/ActuatorSoftwareComponent` was presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EcuHWAbSwComponent sits inbetween the SensorActuator component above the RTE and the MCAL (and maybe some other lower HwAbstraction drivers it might rely on), but within the HwAbstraction layer below the RTE. That's why the EcuHwAbSwComponent is rather a BSW with a BSWMD.

Look into the AUTOSAR_TPS_SoftwareComponentTemplate chapter 10.